# Merging meshes opengl and libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am using the following code to merge several meshes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.obsgolem.crystalia.gfx.Renderer;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class MeshBatch
{

    private final static VertexAttribute[] attributeConfig = new VertexAttribute[]{
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"),
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, "a_color"),
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3, "a_normal")};
    private final static int VERTEX_SIZE = 3 + 1 + 3;

    private Mesh m;
    private List<Float> vertices = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private List<Short> indices = new ArrayList<Short>();

    public void addMesh(float[] vert, short[] ind)
    {
        int offset = (vertices.size() / VERTEX_SIZE);

        //You have to throw an exception when you get over the limit of short indices
        if (offset + vert.length / VERTEX_SIZE > Short.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("blablabla");
        }

        for (short i : addOffset(ind, offset)) {
            indices.add(i);
        }

        for (float v : vert) {
            vertices.add(v);
        }
    }

    public short[] addOffset(short[] ind, int offset)
    {
        short[] indarr = new short[ind.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ind.length; ++i) {
            //Do you really need this check? You are the only one using this code
            //so make sure that you never provide a null value. If you really want to have a chekc throw an exception instead
            short value = ind[i];//ind[i] == null ? 0 : ind[i];
            indarr[i] = (short) (value + offset);
        }
        return indarr;
    }


    public void end()
    {
        m = new Mesh(false, vertices.size(), indices.size(), attributeConfig);
        m.setVertices(Renderer.makeFloatArray(vertices));
        m.setIndices(Renderer.makeShortArray(indices));
    }

    public void render()
    {
        Renderer.getInstance().render(m);
    }
}
```

However when I draw using this class I get strange effects with lighting. With this mesh the light is brighter for all other objects while the one rendered with has lighting which looks flat. With the normal way(Seperate meshes for each object) I get nice smooth lighing. Here are two screenshots I took:

With merged mesh:
[image: Merged mesh lighting]

Without merged mesh:
[image: Smooth per pixel lighting without merged mesh]

What is causing this problem, and how can it effect the lighting of another mesh? My vertices are sent in with the proper format(3 floats for vertices, 1 for color, and 3 for normals). My indices are also working. The problem occurs only when the mesh is actually rendered. Without it lighting works perfectly. I think that the problem has something to do with the normals, but I can not figure out what that problem might be.

**Edit:** I think I have fixed the problem. When I switched the tiles from using seperate meshes to meshbatch the lighting fixed itself. How could this happen?

Comment: I have no idea about libgdx, so I don't want to answer.  However, a few things that may help:  (1) Flat shading means that all of the normals of a face are pointing in the same direction.  So try printing them out and see if that's the case.  (2)  It could also be a problem with the calculation of the distance away from the light.  Maybe all your normals are pointed in the same direction, but you are computing the distance to the light to be the same for all vertices.  I have no idea what lighting model you use, so I can't help more.

Comment: @Max I am using per pixel lighting, diffuse only. Each mesh is a cube.  Aren't cube faces supposed to have normals pointing in one direction?

Comment: Not enough information here to say anything useful. Though it does seem odd that you send a '4' to VertexAttribute for color if you claim it uses one float, but I have no idea what this class does.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the merged mesh effecting the other lighting. Instead of normalizing the distance from the light I am now dividing the distance from light by the sqrt of the length of that variable. It seems to have helped with that problem but not with the meshbatch lighting problem.

Comment: @tim The colorpacked is 4 floats packed into one float. That bit of code works, I know that.

Comment: Ignore my comment about fixing it. That was the wrong solution.

Comment: @jbills: It looked like 2 quads to me.  Regarding your question with cube face normals: it really depends.  You can make a cube where all normals in a face point perpendicular to the face.  That would make the cube look very flatly shaded.  Usually people make the normals of the cube point radially "outward" from the center of the cube.  This makes a nicer shading.  In any case, for a general mesh (that you would draw in Blender, e.g.), the normals are calculated as averages of all the faces adjoining the normal.  That makes the best looking lighting.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, but that does not help with my original problem. It is only the combined mesh that has this problem.

Comment: @jbills: Check (print) the combined mesh normals.  Your lighting model description is weird, the "distance to the light" should be difference of "light position" and "vertex position" coordinates.

Comment: Here is a print out of the vertices for the combined cube: http://pastebin.com/bLzfTRu1 I seem to have fixed the problem though. By combining the tiles into a meshbatch the lighting returns to smooth. What I need now is an explanation of how that could work.

Comment: @jbills: I don't know precisely what you are printing out there, but this is very suspicious (-1.4545402E38).  It's a very _very_ big number.  If the normals are correctly printed, something's very wrong with your normals...

Comment: I can not easily print out the normals of individual meshes. I am printing out the interleaved vertices, colors, and and normals. The vertices are first, followed by a packed color(the large float), followed by the normals. I have looked the over, and they seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work nicely for the Asker of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937752/1895303):

```
public static Mesh mergeMeshes(AbstractList<Mesh> meshes, AbstractList<Matrix4> transformations)
{
    if(meshes.size() == 0) return null;

    int vertexArrayTotalSize = 0;
    int indexArrayTotalSize = 0;

    VertexAttributes va = meshes.get(0).getVertexAttributes();
    int vaA[] = new int [va.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<va.size(); i++)
    {
        vaA[i] = va.get(i).usage;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<meshes.size(); i++)
    {
        Mesh mesh = meshes.get(i);
        if(mesh.getVertexAttributes().size() != va.size()) 
        {
            meshes.set(i, copyMesh(mesh, true, false, vaA));
        }

        vertexArrayTotalSize += mesh.getNumVertices() * mesh.getVertexSize() / 4;
        indexArrayTotalSize += mesh.getNumIndices();
    }

    final float vertices[] = new float[vertexArrayTotalSize];
    final short indices[] = new short[indexArrayTotalSize];

    int indexOffset = 0;
    int vertexOffset = 0;
    int vertexSizeOffset = 0;
    int vertexSize = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<meshes.size(); i++)
    {
        Mesh mesh = meshes.get(i);

        int numIndices = mesh.getNumIndices();
        int numVertices = mesh.getNumVertices();
        vertexSize = mesh.getVertexSize() / 4;
        int baseSize = numVertices * vertexSize;
        VertexAttribute posAttr = mesh.getVertexAttribute(Usage.Position);
        int offset = posAttr.offset / 4;
        int numComponents = posAttr.numComponents;

        { //uzupelnianie tablicy indeksow
            mesh.getIndices(indices, indexOffset);
            for(int c = indexOffset; c < (indexOffset + numIndices); c++)
            {
                indices[c] += vertexOffset;
            }
            indexOffset += numIndices;
        }

        mesh.getVertices(0, baseSize, vertices, vertexSizeOffset);
        Mesh.transform(transformations.get(i), vertices, vertexSize, offset, numComponents, vertexOffset, numVertices);
        vertexOffset += numVertices;
        vertexSizeOffset += baseSize;
    }

    Mesh result = new Mesh(true, vertexOffset, indices.length, meshes.get(0).getVertexAttributes());
    result.setVertices(vertices);
    result.setIndices(indices);
    return result;
} 

    public static Mesh copyMesh(Mesh meshToCopy, boolean isStatic, boolean removeDuplicates, final int[] usage) {
    // TODO move this to a copy constructor?
    // TODO duplicate the buffers without double copying the data if possible.
    // TODO perhaps move this code to JNI if it turns out being too slow.
    final int vertexSize = meshToCopy.getVertexSize() / 4;
    int numVertices = meshToCopy.getNumVertices();
    float[] vertices = new float[numVertices * vertexSize];
    meshToCopy.getVertices(0, vertices.length, vertices);
    short[] checks = null;
    VertexAttribute[] attrs = null;
    int newVertexSize = 0;
    if (usage != null) {
        int size = 0;
        int as = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < usage.length; i++)
            if (meshToCopy.getVertexAttribute(usage[i]) != null) {
                size += meshToCopy.getVertexAttribute(usage[i]).numComponents;
                as++;
            }
        if (size > 0) {
            attrs = new VertexAttribute[as];
            checks = new short[size];
            int idx = -1;
            int ai = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < usage.length; i++) {
                VertexAttribute a = meshToCopy.getVertexAttribute(usage[i]);
                if (a == null)
                    continue;
                for (int j = 0; j < a.numComponents; j++)
                    checks[++idx] = (short)(a.offset/4 + j);
                attrs[++ai] = new VertexAttribute(a.usage, a.numComponents, a.alias);
                newVertexSize += a.numComponents;
            }
        }
    }
    if (checks == null) {
        checks = new short[vertexSize];
        for (short i = 0; i < vertexSize; i++)
            checks[i] = i;
        newVertexSize = vertexSize;
    }

    int numIndices = meshToCopy.getNumIndices();
    short[] indices = null; 
    if (numIndices > 0) {
        indices = new short[numIndices];
        meshToCopy.getIndices(indices);
        if (removeDuplicates || newVertexSize != vertexSize) {
            float[] tmp = new float[vertices.length];
            int size = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numIndices; i++) {
                final int idx1 = indices[i] * vertexSize;
                short newIndex = -1;
                if (removeDuplicates) {
                    for (short j = 0; j < size && newIndex < 0; j++) {
                        final int idx2 = j*newVertexSize;
                        boolean found = true;
                        for (int k = 0; k < checks.length && found; k++) {
                            if (tmp[idx2+k] != vertices[idx1+checks[k]])
                                found = false;
                        }
                        if (found)
                            newIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                if (newIndex > 0)
                    indices[i] = newIndex;
                else {
                    final int idx = size * newVertexSize;
                    for (int j = 0; j < checks.length; j++)
                        tmp[idx+j] = vertices[idx1+checks[j]];
                    indices[i] = (short)size;
                    size++;
                }
            }
            vertices = tmp;
            numVertices = size;
        }
    }

    Mesh result;
    if (attrs == null)
        result = new Mesh(isStatic, numVertices, indices == null ? 0 : indices.length, meshToCopy.getVertexAttributes());
    else
        result = new Mesh(isStatic, numVertices, indices == null ? 0 : indices.length, attrs);
    result.setVertices(vertices, 0, numVertices * newVertexSize);
    result.setIndices(indices);
    return result;
}
```