# merging multiple models in libgdx

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, models

Is it possible to merge two (or more models) in libgdx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved. Libgdx library has some bugs which cause many problems with merging different models (while the same models can be merged without any problem). I found an apropriate solution to this problem and it allowed me to use VBO system without properly.

[image]

For more information please refer to those links:

[slow model batch rendering in libGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170758/slow-renderer-in-libgdx)

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10842