# LIBGDX 3D : Turning textures off on shader : OpenGL

Tags: opengl, libgdx, kotlin

Sorry if question is a bit niche. I wrote some code a few years back and it renders many meshes as 1 big mesh for performance.

What I am trying to do now is just render meshes without textures, so a single colour

```
boxModel = modelBuilder.createBox(10f, 10f, 10f, Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE), ColorAttribute.createSpecular(Color.RED), FloatAttribute.createShininess(15f)), (VertexAttributes.Usage.Position or VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal or VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates).toLong()) // or VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates
            for (x in 1..10) {
                for (y in 1..10) {
                    modelInstance = ModelInstance(boxModel, x * 15f, 0.0f, y * 15f)
                    chunks2[0].addMesh(modelInstance.model.meshes, modelInstance.transform, btBoxShape(Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f)))
                }
            }

chunks2[0].mergeBaby()
```

So I build up the giant mesh and then render it

```
shaderProgram.begin()
texture.bind()
shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined)
shaderProgram.setAttributef("a_color", 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
shaderProgram.setUniformi("u_texture", 0)

renderChunks()
shaderProgram.end()
```

This works for textured stuff great and the right texture is shown etc but the base colour (I guess that's "a_color" is set to white) where I actually want it to use what I supplied in the Material property.

Comment: why use a shader? you can create a material and choose the defuse color.

Comment: I am using the function from heres answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170758/slow-model-batch-rendering-in-libgdx/20937752#20937752